# What does the ${$key} expression mean in "foreach" construction?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In my project I receive data from an html form into the _POST massive. Then I need to pass it into the _SESSION massive, and as far as I understand, I need to validate this received data to keep on working with it.
Trying to understand how to do this I found an exapmle of good-working code, but I don't understand it quite well. Please help me clarify what this code really means.

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    'b' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    'c' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    'd' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
        );

$arr1 = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $arr);

foreach ($all2 as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

In fact the problem remains with

```
{
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

I can't find what does the expression ${$key} mean.

Comment: `${$key}` is dynamically assigning the array_keys as a variable. For example, `$a = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`.

Comment: That's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Stay far far away from this or else you will hate yourself when you need to debug this in the future. You can easily achieve the same functionality via `extract($all2); $_SESSION = $all2;` instead of the `foreach(){}` code

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really useful.

Comment: It's a great way to pollute your scope and compromise your security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates variables based on the value of the key in the array.

So if `$_POST['name']` exists, and you're looping through it, it creates a variable called `$name` and sets it equal to `$value`.

`$_SESSION[$key]` in the above example is also setting the name key in the SESSION array.

I find this practice to be useful, because instead of having to type `<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> you can use <?php echo $name; ?>`.  However, it has its own risks, because if `name` isn't passed in the post, you're attempting to echo a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, seemes really an interesting feature, although I see that its a bit controversial. Anyway now I have everything to continue learning about this.

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically assigning a variable known as a variable variable. Take this example

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    ${$k} = $v;

echo $foo; // bar
```

Since the key in this array is foo, we are assigning the key as a variable.